# make fails with linker complaining for duplicate symbols

Tags: c

I have 2 C programs present in a directory with a common header file while performing make, the linker is raising an error for duplicate symbol.

```
cat inventory.h
const char *jpeg_perf_inputs[] = {
    "perf_11k_img_jpg",
    "Sample_jpg_image_1mb_jpg"};

const char *zip_large_input [] = {
    "a.zip",
    "b.zip"
};

uint32_t num_jpeg_perf_inputs = sizeof(jpeg_perf_inputs) / sizeof(jpeg_perf_inputs[0]);
uint32_t num_zip_large_inputs = sizeof(zip_large_input) / sizeof(zip_large_input[0]);
```

...

```
cat jpeg_perf_test.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include"inventory.h"
void parse_jpeg_arr(){
for(int i= 0; i<num_jpeg_perf_inputs;i++)
    printf("Image name: %s",jpeg_perf_inputs[i]);
}

cat basic_zip.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include"inventory.h"
void parse_zip_arr(){
for(int i= 0; i<num_zip_large_inputs;i++)
    printf("ZIP file name: %s",zip_large_input[i]);
}
```

Error

```
duplicate symbol _zip_large_input in:
    build/posix/obj/apps/integration_apps/zip/jpeg_perf_test.o
    build/posix/obj/apps/integration_apps/zip/basic_zip.o
```

Comment: what error(s) are you getting and what commands are you using to compile your programs?

Comment: the make file is from the company project which is too complex for me to understand, I'll update the error

Comment: Doesn't matter about the commands - the error shows us you're only compiling 1 program not 2 as you state in the question

Comment: Putting variable declarations into a header file is considered bad practice - header files should be *idempotent*.  Now you know why.

Comment: Actually @ChrisTurner the OP is not even showing one program, since neither source files have a `main`.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because you put definitions into header file. Each *translation unit* in which the header is included produces a separate definition for the linker, which results in a duplicate definition error.

Definitions belong in an implementation file. Only declarations must go into the header; implementations must go into a separate file:

inventory.h

```
extern const char *jpeg_perf_inputs[];
extern const char *zip_large_input [];

extern size_t num_jpeg_perf_inputs;
extern size_t num_zip_large_inputs;
```

inventory.c

```
#include"inventory.h"

const char *jpeg_perf_inputs[] = {
    "perf_11k_img_jpg",
    "Sample_jpg_image_1mb_jpg"};

const char *zip_large_input [] = {
    "a.zip",
    "b.zip"
};
size_t num_jpeg_perf_inputs = sizeof(jpeg_perf_inputs) / sizeof(jpeg_perf_inputs[0]);
size_t num_zip_large_inputs = sizeof(zip_large_input) / sizeof(zip_large_input[0]);
```

The header is sufficient to compile the dependencies, while the implementation produces a single instance of definition for each object.

Note the use of `size_t` in place of `int32_t`.